# Transferring values between two forms in Qt

Tags: qt

I have a `lineEdit` called `myVal` in a form called `MainWindow`. In a second form entitled `SecondWindow`, I have a `lineEdit` called `myVal2` and an Ok button called `OKButton`.

I think the best solution is to use signals and slots. I searched different sites but I tried to use.
`connect(ui.OKButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), MainWindow, SLOT(transferValue));`

However, I was unable to get it to work.

Comment: I've outlined what your general approach should be in an answer below. If you are having trouble with the signals and slots, be sure to update your question, or post a comment that conveys any specific error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind, your second window should subclass QDialog, as said above.

Then, if you want to retrieve your LineEdit value, just provide an accessor :

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog {
public:
    QString myVal() const { return ui->lineEdit->text(); }
};
```

To show your dialog, use exec and check the return value :

```
MyDialog dialog;
if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) { /* The user clicked Ok */ 
    const QString val = dialog.myVal();
}
```

Your second window doesn't need to be aware of your MainWindow and its internals

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would depend on the nature of your second window.

If your second window is a modeless dialog, signals and slots would be the way to go. Connect the OK button's `clicked()` signal to a slot implemented by your main window. Inside your slot, read the value of the line edit in your second window and copy it to the line edit in your main window.

If your second window is a modal dialog, then you don't really need signals and slots. You should be using a `QDialog` derived class and show it using a call to `exec()`. When this function returns, the return value indicates if the user clicked OK or Cancel. Based on this value, you can decide if you should copy the line edit value or not.

Answer (score -1):

I would defenetly override the constructor of the SecondWindow and pass as argument an instance of the MainWindow then you can access without constraints the public variables of the  class MainWindow.